# Firebase auth create user again issues

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

my app firstly only contains google login and now I removed it and now users need to login using email and password but when my old customer (who already login with google) unable to signup with old email address it showing "The email address is already in use by another account." and they don't have any password? How to solve this issue

Comment: Can't you delete their account and let them sign up with email and password?

Comment: then uid will change, all history  stored with uid and if it change old user cant trace their old activities

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking Account linking is all you need.

Comment: i am using angular 2 ionic 2

Answer (score 0):

problem solved by implementing  this.afAuth.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(this.email).catch(error=>{}).then(res=>{});